# Call one single function randomly

Tags: python, function, random, call

I am making this chat-respond program, my goal is for the computer to pick a question out of the database randomly and able to respond base on the input answer. There are no error notices but the problem is that the first question it asks does not return an answer and it asks all the question on the list, not just one. How do I fix this? Thanks for the help!

```
import random

x=input("What is your name? ")

def feeling():
    return input("How are you feeling right now " +str(x)+"? ")

def homesick():
    return input("Do you miss your home? ")

def miss():
    return input("Who do you miss?")

prompts = [feeling,homesick,miss]
response = random.choice(prompts)()
 
if feeling()==("tired"):
    Tired=['I wish I can make you feel better.','I hope school is not making you feel stressed.','You deserve the right to relax.']
    print(random.choice(Tired))

if homesick()==("yes"):
    yes=["Don't worry, you will be home soon......",'I am protecting your family and loved ones, trust me on this.',"Your kingdoms has been waiting for a long time, they'd forgiven your mistakes"]
    print(random.choice(yes))

if miss()==("my mom"):
    print("Mom will be in town soon")
```

Comment: Add the specific error you're getting. From glancing at the code, `random.choice(question)()` can't work, because `question` is a list of strings, but you're executing them as if they were functions.

Comment: As a general comment: You may want to look up 'PEP 8'. It describes a general Python coding style, which might become useful if you start writing big codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input()` returns a string, not a function object.

Therefore `question` is a list of strings, and you cannot call a `str` object like `random.choice(question)()`

If you want to prompt for random input, then you would do this, for example

```
prompts = ["How are you feeling right now " +str(x)+"? "]
response = input(random.choice(prompts))
```

Then, you need to make your if statements use `response` variable

If you want random functions, you will need a `def`

```
def miss():
    return input("What do you miss? ")

prompts = [miss]
response = random.choice(prompts)()
```

By the way, you should loop using a `while`, not calling the function itself